# group numbering of data

Tags: r, number-formatting

I have two files of data and I am going to do the group numbering of the first file based on the numbers in the second file.(like the image)

[image]
here is the code:

```
graphics.off()
rm(list=ls())

df110<-read.csv('C:/Users/Shel3/Desktop/tmr/D1.csv')
df210<-read.csv("C:/Users/Shel3/Desktop/tmr/S1.csv")

mat1<-array(, dim=c(nrow(df110), 1))


b<-cbind(mat1, df110)
i<-1
for(i in 1:nrow(b)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df210)){
    df210[j,2] 
    b[i:df210[j,2],2] = j 
    i=df210[j,2]+1
  }
}
```

the problem is that the program starts to run but it seems that it never ends the processing which for this simple process is very strange!!
Does anyone can please help me how to solve it.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Why are you updating `i` in the last line of your `i` loop? This, in general, is discouraged. Maybe try a different approach without any loops.

Comment: @Edward because if I do not do that the second loop would be i=2 i.e. the numbering starts from the second data (overlap of first loop and second loo). Please let me know if I am making mistakes or I did not get it very well, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Perhaps if you provide some data, not an image, and explain __exactly__ what you want to do ("group numbering" is very unclear), you'll get better help here. It seems to me that all you want to do is tabulate the `No.` column in file 2 to produce the `Count` column. If so, use `table(No.)`.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the value of the "i" index variable inside your loop this is bad programming practice.

It looks like you are trying create a sequence of numbers based on file2.  The `rep()` can preform this in one line.

```
index<-c(1:5)
repeats <-c(2, 1, 3, 2, 4)
rep(index, times=repeats)
#[1] 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e. but I do not want to do it by hand, as it is not the data that I have (my file has more than 2 000 000 data :)

Comment: I did this is an example. The "index" and "repeats" vectors can be read/created from your file.  You problem statement is not very clear.  If this not what you are looking for let me know and I'll delete the answer.

Comment: yes you are totally correct! I do not know why I complicated it to solve it. Thanks friend